# Adding contents via ItemsSource to a WPF datagridview

Tags: c#

I read an xml file like so

```
    string appDataPath1 = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
    string configPath1 = appDataPath1 + "/LWRF/ReaderProfiles";
    string fn = System.IO.Path.Combine(configPath1 + ComboBoxProfiles.Text);
        _currentProfile.Clear();
        try
        {
            Log("Loading profile: " + fn);
            _currentProfile.ReadXml(fn);
            _dgvProfile.ItemsSource = _currentProfile.DefaultView;
        }
        catch
        {

        }
```

What else do I need to do to make the xml file contents display in the gridview? I added this code to a `ComboBox_SelectionChanged` event but my datagridview is blank even after the selection changes.

Comment: is there any data in `_currentProfile.DefaultView` ?

Comment: yes there was data in it. thanks for responding sa_ddam213!

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are missing a `/` in configPath1 :

```
string configPath1 = appDataPath1 + "/LWRF/ReaderProfiles/";
```

Comment: AbZy you were exactly right. Once I implemented your idea it worked great and populated the dataviewgrid perfectly!Many thanks, saroj